# SMack API in java

Tags: java

```
public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
        if (message.getType() == Message.Type.chat)
            System.out.println(chat.getParticipant() + " says: "+ message.getBody());
      **processmsg** = message.getBody();
        System.out.println("Message from Friend -----:"+**processmsg**);

    }
```

Hi.how to use this **processmsg** String in another method.if i use outside this method i get null value. plz reply soon

Answer (score 1):

Store processmsg as an instance variable in the class that contains processMessage

```
class Foo {
   private String processmsg;

   public void processMessage(Chat char, Message message) {
      processmsg = message.getBody();
   } 

   public void bar() {
      // do whatever you want
   }
}
```

Obviously you'll need to check that it's been assigned and so on before you use it (e.g. you couldn't use bar before processMessage), but you get the idea!